# How can be Nagios RRD database imported to Influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb, nagiosxi

Is there any way we can import the NagiosXI RRD database into Influxdb which can be further pushed to the grafana dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pnp4nagios for this..?

Answer (score 0):

i got that as a workaround but that is not as much helpful as other data sources.